# Plotting vector in 3D in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, plot, matlab-figure

I'm studying Linear Algebra.  I would like to visualize a vector `[2, 1, 2]` in 3D.  I used the following command:

```
quiver3(0,0,0,2,1,2)
```

And either my understanding of Linear Algebra is off or I'm doing something wrong with MATLAB.  But what the plot looks like to me is that it's plotting vector `[1.8, 0.9, 1.8]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, [`quiver3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/quiver3.html) will use whatever scaling that optimizes the display of the vectors.

> `quiver3(...,scale)` **automatically scales the vectors to prevent them from overlapping**, and then multiplies them by scale. scale = 2 doubles their relative length, and scale = 0.5 halves them. Use scale = 0 to plot the vectors without the automatic scaling.

You'll want to specify the `scale` parameter as `0` to prevent this automatic scaling and to accurately represent the data that you provide

```
quiver3(0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0);
```

[image]